# Frequency of the majuscule ß (ẞ) in modern German

Tags: spelling, typography, eszett

I've looked at the [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/what-is-the-appropriate-capitalization-of-ss) on here that relates to this one, but it doesn't really discuss the use of the majuscule eszett (ẞ). I've never seen it used but how often does the ẞ get used? I know the [Gießener Zeitung](http://www.giessener-zeitung.de/global/start/) uses the ẞ because their [title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTRbE.png) is always written in all caps and I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHF6M.png) in the *Ständiger Ausschuss für geographische Namen (StAGN)* published by the *Geschäftsstelle des StAGN im Bundesamt für Kartographie und Geodäsie*.

Instead of using the majuscule eszett (if isn't a common, mainstream thing) is it OK and accepted to use a regular one along with capitals?

> GOETHESTRAßE

or should you just use two capital S's?

Comment: Also related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5611/is-it-an-error-when-i-do-not-use-ss-when-it-is-necessary

Comment: See also http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Gro.C3.9Fschreibweise

Comment: @stackunderflow: »Eszett« is only in Germany used as name for the letter *ß*. In Austria you call it »Scharfes s«. (It is not used in Switzerland, so I don't know how they call it there.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Official rules

As of 29.06.2017, the official spelling rules allow to use the capital eszett (ẞ) and *SS* when capitalising *ß;* they do not allow using a lowercase *ß* (§ 25 E3):

> Bei Schreibung mit Großbuchstaben schreibt man *SS.* Daneben ist auch die Verwendung des Großbuchstabens *ẞ* möglich. Beispiel: *Straße – STRASSE – STRAẞE*

#### Frequency of usage

From my observations, *ß* is most often capitalised as the lowercase *ß* (despite this being wrong), considerably less often as *SS* and even less often as a capital eszett *(ẞ).* However, the latter is used with surprisingly increasing frequency. [This article](http://www.typografie.info/3/page/artikel.htm/_/wissen/grosses-eszett-anwendungsbeispiele) features some recent uses, including the corporate designs of RWE (a major German electricity company), the SPD (a major German political party), the German football association, and the University of Weimar.

#### My (hopefully informed) opinion

- If it is not a logo or similar: Check if you really want to use all caps, since they decrease legibility, make the text optically disharmonious, and a lot of people feel shouted at by them. Consider using small caps or another type of typographical emphasis (bold, italics, …) instead.
- If you can assure that your text is rendered in a font with a proper capital eszett, use it (GOETHESTRAẞE). This is arguably the alternative which least readers will stumble over. I personally used a small-caps eszett before it became official, in a situation with several readers who where supposed to spot mistakes, and nobody noticed. The design of a capital eszett is good, if it cannot be read as a *B* and if it does not stand out amongst the other capital letters of the font, e.g., by being to narrow (see also [here](http://typography.guru/journal/capital-sharp-s-designs/)).
- Otherwise use *SS* (GOETHESTRASSE). While this is the preferred variant in the official spelling rules, it is more distracting as readers intuitively read it like a lowercase *ss.*
- Never use a lowercase eszett (GOETHESTRAßE), except for forms where names need to be identified correctly and similar. This is not only officially wrong, but also distracting as the lowercase eszett does not harmonise with the other letters.

Comment: I find it somewhat ironical that they wanted to find a single letter capitalization of something that was two letters to begin with. It's not like it's the only polygraph in German.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30808/discussion-on-answer-by-wrzlprmft-frequency-of-the-majuscule-ss--in-modern-ger).

Comment: My up vote was for a decidedly different answer.

Comment: "ß is most often capitalised as ß (despite this being wrong)" — How do you type a capitalised ß anyway?

Comment: @CarstenS: Any change you are not happy with? Mostly, I removed information about the spelling rules and their history that have become obsolete. The remaining content should not have changed dramatically (though I reorganised it).

Comment: Mir gefällt nur der Umfang der Änderung nicht. Die Teile, die Du gelöscht hast, habe ich als interessant in Erinnerung. Die neue Antwort habe ich nicht gelesen.

Comment: @Em1: On [my keyboard](http://neo-layout.org/) it’s [Shift] + [ß]. For other keyboards, we have a question for this, IIRC.

Comment: @CarstenS: Ich kann das zwar nachvollziehen, aber ich denke nicht, dass es sinnvoll ist, für die normalen Anwender (die ich als Zielpublikum dieser Frage und Antwort ansehe) eine komplizierte Übergangssituation zu dokumentieren, die Vergangenheit ist. Wenn Du möchtest, kannst Du aber gerne hierzu eine Frage stellen – gerade da das aktuell ist.

Comment: Das ist ok, ich denke nur nicht, dass es sinnvoll ist, Antworten nach so langer Zeit signifikant zu ändern. Von den 10 Upvotern hat vielleicht keiner die Antwort gelesen.

Comment: @CarstenS: Abgesehen von der Umstrukturierung ist es wirklich nur das Ersetzen von [es ist was im Gange, und zwar …] durch [es ist offiziell]. Die wesentlichen Aussagen sind dieselben.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Mein Punkt ist, dass auf dem Standard-Keyboard-Layout das ß nur in Kleinschreibweise existiert. Und die Wenigsten benutzen wohl die Neo-Tastatur.

Comment: @Carsten Edits entsperren alle Votes, Du könntest also theoretisch Dein Upvote entfernen

Comment: Es ist alles ok, ich finde es nur etwas schade um das 1919-Zitat.

Answer (score 4):

> or should you just use two capital S's?

Use that one. It's the most common capitalization and I'd recommend it over using lower case.

Alternative spellings are

- `SZ`, which  used to be recommended for ambiguous cases (*Maße* vs *Masse*) and according to Wikipedia, is the default for some specific applications (military typewriters, architectural drawings) and regions (eastern Austria)
- `ẞ`, the actual capital letter (added to DIN in 2007 and Unicode in 2008), which is mainly used in things like signs or logos or in cases where capitalization is used for formal reasons like machine readability and the distinction between `SS` and `ẞ` matters (eg proper names for identification)

Note that capital eszett might become the default spelling in the future (who knows?), but it isn't yet. On the other hand, Switzerland got rid of the `ß` altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Im ORF läuft seit einigen Wochen die Realsatire-Serie »Gemischtes Doppel« mit Thomas Stipsits und Katharina Straßer. Im Vorspann werden die Namen der beiden Hauptdarsteller in Versalschrift angezeigt, dabei wird für das scharfe S in »Straßer« ein großes scharfes S verwendet:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no capital "sharp s", not really. Yes, some fonts have it, and there have been repeated attempts to introduce a majuscule ß, but support is far from widespread. Learners of German would be well-advised to stay away from it. Just use "SS" is you must, and be done with it. It's probably a good thing to avoid all caps anyway.

Comment: Note that the capital eszett became official today.

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning that. The _Rechtschreibrat_ introduced it officially today, together with a few other minor changes. Just so you know: SS instead of ẞ continues to be an accepted alternative.