# Was ist der Zweck des großen Eszetts?

Tags: spelling, reformed-orthography, eszett

Ich lese gerade den Artikel [Das große Eszett ist da!](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/gesellschaft/das-grosse-eszett-ist-da-15083117.html), und trotzdem kann ich nicht verstehen, wozu dieses große Eszett. Meine Frage ist folgende: Gibt es Nomen auf Deutsch, die ich nicht kenne, die mit *ß* anfangen und damit diesen Großbuchstabe benötigen?

Comment: Ist schon bekannt, wie das große Scharf-S (oder auch das große Buckel-S) aussehen soll?

Comment: Ich habe vor einem halben Jahr auf eine andere Frage, die sich um das große scharfe S dreht, ein Beispiel gepostet: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/33673/1487

Comment: Welche Frage lässt der [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Großes_ß) denn offen?

Answer (score 10):

Wenn du in Großbuchstaben schreiben musst. Heißt jemand Meißner oder Meissner wenn da MEISSNER steht?

Für Namen wurde es auch vor allem eingeführt. Da nach alten Regeln hier immer ein großes SS vorgeschrieben war und man das nicht eindeutig zurück übersetzen konnte.

Comment: Das steht auch explizit so im gelinkten Artikel. (Was diese Antwort natürlich nicht falsch macht.)

Comment: _MAẞE_ und _MASSE_ wäre auch ein Beispiel. Bei Namen kommt sogar noch _SZ_ hinzu.

Comment: Die nächste Frage wäre dann aber: Warum einen Großbuchstaben (mit anderer Schreibweise) hinzufügen und nicht einfach bestimmen, dass in diesem Fall derselbe Buchstaben sowohl als Groß- als auch Kleinbuchstaben zu verwenden ist?

Comment: @MartinRosenau Die Antwort ist eher typographisch als orthographisch:
Weil das in den meisten Schriften furchtbar aussieht.
Das kleine ß ist gewöhnlich schmaler als die Großbuchstaben,
in manchen Schriften auch höher, und sticht darum unangenehm
heraus, wenn man es mit Großbuchstaben mischt.