# Kann jemand erklären, wann "ss" und "ß" zu benutzen sind?

Tags: spelling, eszett

Ich habe Deutsch vor dem Rechtschreibereform von 1996 gelernt, übrigens habe ich in der Zwischnzeit vergessen, viel von dem, was ich damals über das Thema, wann man "ss" und wann "ß".  Das alles führt zu vielen Fehlern.  Ich habe [im Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/doppel-s-und-scharfes-s#google_vignette) nachgeschlagen, und ich habe auch [diesen Beitrag](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/when-to-use-%C3%9F-and-ss) hier in StackExchange gesehen.  Dazu kommt [diese Webseite](https://www.nachhilfe-team.net/lernen-leicht-gemacht/ss-oder-sz/).   Man sieht, dass es mit "kurzen" und "langen" Vokalen zu tun hat.  Aber was heißen "lange" und "kurze" Vokale in diesem Kontext?  Die Dauer der Aussprache?  Wie der Vokal klingt (der Kontrast zwischen dem kurzen und dem langen "A" auf Englisch, zum Beispiel)?

Kann jemand mir gut erklären, wie man weiß, was man benutzen soll?  Wenn Ihr bessere Links vorschlagen könnt, die die Sache gut erklären können (vielleicht mit Audio, um die Unterschiede hören zu können), wäre das auch gut!

Comment: Phoneminventar und Hörbeispiele habe ich hier gesammelt: [List of words that demonstrate all German consonant and vowel sounds](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/69717/35111).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Regel in der neuen Rechtschreibung ist, dass man die Frage, ob man *ss* oder *ß* schreibt, nach der Standard-Aussprache des Vokals davor entscheiden kann. Nach "kurzen" Vokalen steht *ss*, nach "langen" Vokalen steht *ß*.

Wichtig ist, dass diese Regel nicht bei der Frage hilft, ob man ein Wort mit "s" oder mit "ss"/"ß" schreibt. Um die Regel oben anwenden zu können, muss man schon vorher wissen, dass das Wort nicht mit nur einem einfachen *s* geschrieben wird.

Es folgen Beispiele für "kurze" und "lange" Vokale mit Links zu Wiktionary, wo jeweils Hörbeispiele und die Aussprache in IPA zu finden sind. Wie man dabei sieht, bezieht sich "kurz" und "lang" hier nicht unbedingt nur auf die zeitliche Länge der Aussprache des Vokals, sondern es sind eigentlich jeweils unterschiedliche Arten, den gleichen Vokal auszusprechen, die meist auch unterschiedlichen Symbolen in IPA entsprechen. Siehe hierzu auch die Antwort von David Vogt [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69709/list-of-words-that-demonstrate-all-german-consonant-and-vowel-sounds/69717#69717).

Kurzes A: [Masse](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Masse), [dass](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dass)
Langes A: [Maß](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ma%C3%9F)

Kurzes E: [besser](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/besser)
Langes E: [Geest](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Geest) (mir fällt kein Beispiel mit lang gesprochenem e und ß danach ein)

Kurzes I: [wissen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wissen)
Langes I: [Spieß](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Spie%C3%9F) (mir fällt kein Beispiel mit lang gesprochenem i und dann ß ein, ein lang gesprochenes i wird im Deutschen normalerweise als ie geschrieben)

Kurzes O: [Ross](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ross), [Posse](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Posse)
Langes O: [groß](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gro%C3%9F)

Kurzes U: [Kuss](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kuss)
Langes U: [Muße](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mu%C3%9Fe), [Gruß](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gru%C3%9F)

Kurzes Ä: du [lässt](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%A4sst), [Pässe](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/P%C3%A4sse)
Langes Ä: [Gefäß](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gef%C3%A4%C3%9F)

Kurzes Ö: [gösse](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%B6sse) (Konjunktiv von *gießen*)
Langes Ö: [Blöße](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bl%C3%B6%C3%9Fe), [größer](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gr%C3%B6%C3%9Fer)

Kurzes Ü: [müssen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%BCssen)
Langes Ü: [Grüße](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BC%C3%9Fe)

Nach Diphthongen (Doppellauten aus zwei Vokalen wie ei, au, eu, äu) steht immer ß, nie ss.

> außen, gleißen, preußisch, äußern

Natürlich gibt es auch Zweifelsfälle, die explizit geregelt sind. Der wahrscheinlich bekannteste ist das Wort "[Spaß](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Spa%C3%9F)", das [in manchen Teilen des deutschen Sprachraums](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/spass/) mit langem *A*, in anderen mit kurzem *A* ausgesprochen wird. In Deutschland schreibt man *Spaß*, in Österreich existiert als Nebenform auch *Spass*.

In der Schweiz wird der Buchstabe *ß* gar nicht verwendet, sondern stattdessen *ss* geschrieben.

Comment: gießen: langes i und ß

Comment: @planetmaker Ja, kann man sicherlich so sehen.

Comment: Nach Diphthongen steht immer ß, nie ss, außer bei der Stadt Neuss und bei Zusammensetzungen wie Eisschnelllauf.

Comment: Aber *Eis* wird mit *s* geschrieben, daher greift die Regel nicht.

Comment: Ich habe heftige Zweifel an der Richtigkeit der Aussage über das Wort »Spaß«. Ich habe dazu eine Frage gestellt: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/76183/1487

Comment: Ein Wort, das in Österreich tatsächlich anders geschrieben wird als in Deutschland ist »Geschoß/Geschoss« (Projektil, Stockwerk). Dieses Wort wird in Deutschland mit einem kurzen O gesprochen und daher »Geschoss« geschrieben. In Österreich ist hingegen die Aussprache mit langem O vorherrschend (besonders bei denen, die vor ca 1990 geboren wurden), daher ist dort »Geschoß« die Hauptform, aber »Geschoss« wird als Nebenform auch geduldet (und vor allem jüngere Österreicher sprechen das Wort mittlerweile auch mit kurzem O).

Comment: Danke, das hilft.  Ich habe den Audios zugehört und ich bermerke die Unterschiede.  Aber -- mindestens für mich -- mir kommen etwas sutil vor.  Meines Erachtens wäre es manchmal möglich, dass solche Unterschiede von verschiedenen Personen produziert werden könnten (z.b. "muss" -- eine Person könnte es lang aussprechen, andere kurz, oder...? )

Comment: @Cerulean, warum sollte jemand "Mus" sagen, wenn er "muss" meint? :) Natürlich gibt es Unterschiede, wo genau die verschiedenen Vokale liegen. Ich erinnere mich auch, dass ich bei einem schwäbischen Sprecher das "a" in "das" als lang empfunden habe. Aber wenn sich bei jemandem alle kurzen Vokale wie die langen anhören, nur kürzer, hört man sofort, dass Deutsch für ihn eine Fremdsprache ist.

Comment: @Cerulean abgesehen von Ausnahmen (wie "Spaß" oder "Geschoss") kann man für das Standarddeutsche tatsächlich sagen, dass es für jeden Vokal in jedem Wort eine "richtige" Aussprache gibt, lang oder kurz, und die kennt im Allgemeinen auch jeder, der das Wort kennt. Oft ist bei deutschen Wörtern die Schreibung auch so festgelegt, dass man die richtige Aussprache erschließen kann. Wenn zum Beispiel zwei gleiche Konsonanten folgen ("Mappe", "müssen"), wird der Vokal kurz gesprochen, wenn ein h folgt, wird er lang gesprochen ("zählen", "gehen") etc.