# Aussprache von "Spaß"

Tags: pronunciation, austrian

In einer [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/76173/1487) zu einer anderen Frage schrieb HalvarF:

> Natürlich gibt es auch Zweifelsfälle, die explizit geregelt sind. Der wahrscheinlich bekannteste ist das Wort "Spaß", das in manchen Teilen des deutschen Sprachraums mit langem A, in anderen mit kurzem A ausgesprochen wird. In Deutschland schreibt man Spaß, in Österreich Spass.

Das zweifle ich, der ich 1965 in Österreich geboren wurde und seitdem dort lebe, auf das heftigste an.

Woher kommt die unsinnige Behauptung, man würde »Spaß« in Österreich mit Doppel-S schreiben? Ich weiß, dass in so gut wie allen Wörterbüchern steht, in Österreich wäre auch die Schreibweise »Spass« erlaubt. Leider steht es sogar so im Österreichischen Wörterbuch, aber das kann nicht stimmen. (Übrigens steht in keinem seriösen Wörterbuch, dass »Spass« die Hauptform oder gar die einzige Form in Österreich wäre. Es ist in Österreich laut ÖWB, [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Spa%C3%9F), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Spa%C3%9F) und [Duden](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Spa%C3%9F) nur eine erlaubte Nebenform; aber selbst das halte ich für falsch.)

Die Schreibweise »Spass« impliziert eine kurze Aussprache des Vokals »a«, und die ist in Österreich schlichtweg nicht zu finden. In meinem ganzen Leben habe ich noch nie einen Österreicher dieses Wort mit einem kurzem A sprechen gehört.

Wenn jemand dieses Wort mit einem kurzen A ausspricht (was der einzige Grund für die Rechtfertigung der Schreibweise »Spass« wäre), dann sind das meiner persönlichen Wahrnehmung nach immer Menschen aus Norddeutschland, die eine besonders hanseatisch-preußische Aussprache pflegen. (Bei »Spass« mit kurzem A drängt sich bei mir das Bild eines preußischen Feldwebels auf, der seinen Soldaten mit strengem Ton befiehlt, gut gelaunt zu sein. Das ist sehr weit weg von der österreichischen Gemütlichkeit, mit der wir dieses Wort aussprechen.)

Daher sollte, wie ich meine, die Schreibweise »Spass« eher in Norden Deutschlands eine erlaubte Nebenform sein, aber auf gar keinen Fall in Österreich.

Daher würde ich nun gerne wissen, wer dieses Wort tatsächlich bevorzugt mit kurzem A ausspricht, und wo Leute daheim sind, die das tun.

Comment: Ich (Hintergrund Österreich) spreche es immer mit langem "a" aus, habe aber auch noch nie einen deutschen getroffen, der es kurz ausgesprochen hätte. Natürlich wird die abgeleitete österreichische Form "Spassettl" mit kurzem 'a' gesprochen, aber hier haben wir ja auch ein -ss.

Comment: Eine meiner Meinung nach interessantere Variante zu dem Thema ist das Wort "Maß": Es wird im Sinn von "das Maß" natürlich auch überall lang ausgesprochen, aber wenn man in Bayern "die Maß"  (im Sinn von "1 Liter") sagt, wird es kurz ausgesprochen, obwohl hier die Schreibung mit 'ß'  üblich ist.

Comment: @user1934428 DWDS zumindest ist der Meinung, dass "die Mass" richtig und "die Maß" nur eine populäre Nebenform ist. Ich habe erst aus deinem Kommentar gelernt, dass das Wort in Bayern mit kurzem a gesprochen wird, was sich auf Youtube auch leicht bestätigen ließ.

Comment: @HalvarF : Ich habe davon auch gehört, aber es ist zumindest in Bayern in geschriebenen Texten sehr selten. "Mass" ist sicher eine erlaubgte Form,  sieht für mich aber irgendwie "preussisch" aus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Antwort findet sich im Atlas der Alltagssprache basierend auf einer Erhebung im Jahr 2012. Typischerweise findet man die Aussprache mit kurzem Vokal im südwestlichen Sprachraum. Hanseatisch-Norddeutsch oder preußisch ist sie keinesfalls, österreichisch eher auch nicht (vielleicht gelegentlich in West-Österreich), sondern hauptsächlich (ober)rheinisch, in der Pfalz und im Saarland sowie der Schweiz und im Elsass zu finden:

> Adelungs Bemerkung, „in manchen Provinzen“ werde das a auch kurz gesprochen wie im Italienischen, macht sichtbar, dass schon vor 200 Jahren diese zwei Aussprachen nebeneinander existierten. Auch das DWB (Bd. 16, Sp. 1959) weist darauf hin, dass „in manchen gegenden, besonders des eigentlich hd. sprachgebiets, die historisch richtige aussprache mit kurzem a (ital. spăsso) über die grenzen mundartlichen gebrauchs hinaus geltung hat.“, so im Alemannischen, Schwäbischen, Bairischen, in der Wetterau und ebenso in Westfalen (anders als sonst im Niederdeutschen).

https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/spass/

Comment: Genau diese Karte hatte ich ja in der Antwort auch verlinkt und war selbst etwas erstaunt, warum es sowohl in wiktionary als auch DWDS ausgerechnet für Österreich als Schreibweise angegeben war. Das mit der Nebenform habe ich in den Wörterbüchern anscheinend tatsächlich falsch interpretiert - wenn es in Österreich hauptsächlich benutzt würde, wäre es bezogen auf den deutschen Sprachraum ja immer noch eine Nebenform.